# -moz-transform CSS doesn't help to prevent unnecessary page break during printing on Firefox

Tags: html, jquery, css, firefox

I have two `<table>`s, `header` and `details` respectively as shown below:

```
<table id="header">
   <!-- many rows here -->
</table>
<table id="details" style="break-before: always;">
   <!-- many rows here -->
</table>
```

As you can see, I want the `details` always be printed in the new page and **NOT the `header`**. When the `header` grows slightly more rows, the last row of `header` goes beyond the first page, so I fixed it with the following on Google Chrome:

```
$("body").css("zoom", 0.93);
```

However, for Firefox, I can't make it work even with the following:

```
$("body").css("-moz-transform", "scale(0.9)");
```

Looks like Firefox is **always retaining the original page break even after scaling down**, which means the last `tr` of `header` always goes to the second page. I even tried the following but no luck:

```
<!-- last row of header table -->
<tr style="break-before: avoid;">
```

How can I make it work for Firefox? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure if it helps or not but try the ```page-break-after``` or ```page-break-inside``` css properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, the following works although it seemed to be impossible for the page margin to increase as the contents scaled down on Firefox:

```
/* For Chrome */
$("body").css("zoom", 0.93);
/* For Firefox */
$("body").css("-moz-transform", "scale(0.93)");
$('head').append('<style>@page{margin: 0.3cm;}</style>');
```